# Make-like Build System that Accepts Spaces in Filenames and Directories

Tags: makefile, filenames, spaces, directory

Can anyone recommend a good build system that does not choke on file and directory names with spaces in them?  I am looking for one that requires no kludges if at all possible.  The application I have is to demonstrate bulk picture conversion to a non-Linux user to demonstrate the 'Power of Linux'.

Note that I will be showing this to them on their own files, which I am not assuming follow any kind of 'good naming practice'.  I will not ask them to change any file names or directory names just to work for the demonstration.  I will also not be telling them off for using "bad file names", whatever they are.

Having a 'make-like' system is not essential, but would be good if at all possible.  Two systems spring to mind: ant (although too verbose) and SCons (haven't tried it yet).

Does anybody out there have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A build tool seems like overkill, and needlessly complex if your goal is to show off how easily you can do tasks like this.  A couple of trivial alternatives (assuming your conversion program is called `./convert`):

- **Bash:** `for n in * ; do ./convert "$n" ; done`
- **find:**  `find . -type f -exec ./convert \{} \;`
- **GNU parallel:** `find . -type f | parallel ./convert`

Comment: melski, that's a good guess, the program to convert the pictures is in fact called convert.  The reason I am using  a build tool so that (i) the collection can be _incrementally_ updated efficiently (my picture collection has 9000 images in it) and (ii) it can be _proven_ that all the converted pictures are up to date _and_ there are no missing ones.